# JavaFX WebView font issue on Mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx

Some sites show gibberish characters instead of the correct text. It only happens on Macs.

For example with GMapsFX: 
[image]

[Online site](http://www.firmenabc.at/result.aspx?what=Babinsky%20KG&where=%3D2020%20Hollabrunn&exact=false&inTitleOnly=false&l=&si=0&iid=&sid=&did=&cc=): [image]

Might be related to OS X 10.11 or 10.12. I tested it with Java 1.8.0_121.

Is there any fix or workaround for this issue?

Comment: after several hours I found a workaround, that was ok for my application. I set a listener to the `documentProperty` of the `WebEngine`. Then as soon as the Document is available I run a javascript code by `webEngine.executeScript()`, that is iterating over all elements I identified before in the browser, and set the inline style, that will  override the font from css-file: `nodes[i].style.fontFamily = 'Serif';`. Pretty nasty, I know, but that was the best solution I was able to found... Hmm, I think that will not work for you, since you probably have dynamic HTML

Answer (score 4):

The error, in my case, was not related to system font. I solved the problem by setting the user agent for the web engine. Here is the string I used (Firefox on Windows x64):

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0`

Comment: Pretending to be Windows, when you are Mac might not be such a good idea. It can cause other unintended side effects. I fixed it like this: `engine.setUserAgent(engine.getUserAgent().replace("Macintosh; ", ""));` I believe the problem is: The server that delivers the fonts uses the userAgent to determine which font to send. And when it makes a mistake due to a misleading userAgent it delivers the wrong one. And further i suppose that Mac can not handle the delivered format and gibberish is what you end up with.

Answer (score 1):

please load all font in system when java application launched.
but is not best answer...sorry

```
List<String> fontFamilies = Font.getFamilies();
for (String fontFamily: fontFamilies) {
   Font.font(fontFamily);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific build of OpenJDK that doesn't seem to have these problems. If you are among the affected Mac users, please switch to that version of OpenJDK by following the instructions below.

Download and install the Azul build of OpenJDK 11 version found [here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-11-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk-fx) (scroll to the bottom of the page) Remember to choose the `JDK FX` version (not any other versions).

Recommended: Remove the other versions of OpenJDK so that you do not accidentally launch the JAR using the wrong version ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwV_L3lKYYw) video shows how)

After installation, the command `java --version` should give the following output:

```
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
And `whereis java` should output `/usr/bin/java`
```

Recommended: Set the `JAVA_HOME`/`JDK_HOME` system variables to point to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home`